# Offset Position breaks on android chrome browser

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I have multiple card elements on a page. On click of any action on one card, I move to the next card. Here, an implementation has been made to animate the body to the next card element using Jquery's animate().

It works fine for all the cases except one **when the Android keyboard opens up automatically (If the card has any input fields)**.
To calculate the value of scrollTop, I am using the offsetTop value of the element.

Any suggestions or pointers are really appreciated.